# kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- pry-byebug (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm following along this tutorial on rspec using this page: [Test First: Learn Ruby](http://testfirst.org/learn_ruby) and using this Github repo: [Github Repo for same course using rspec v3](https://github.com/vikingeducation/learn_ruby). My issue is that after cloning the repo, running `bundle install` in the root directory, and then `rspec --init` to create the spec_helper.rb file, I run `rake spec` and I end up with this error regarding a dependency: `~\.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require': cannot load such file -- pry-byebug (LoadError)`

The thing is that the pry-byebug gem is installed. I've uninstalled and reinstalled it, removed the repo and restarted, but no matter what I get this error, and I'm not sure how to resolve it.

I'm new to programming and to this site so any information I've left out I can easily provide.

**EDIT**: I eventually figured out my rookie mistake: there's a folder in the path that has a space in it. Changing that fixed the issue.

Comment: does `bundle show pry-byebug` print the path to the installed gem?

Comment: @zetetic In attempting to check this out I did some more testing things out and on a hunch, I changed part of the path to the project to no longer include a folder with spaces. Rookie move, I know. That resolved my issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spaces in the file path to the project cause problems, apparently. I edited the offending folder and rspec then worked as intended.